# Scheduling a parameterized build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

How to schedule a build to run if it has been 3 days since another projects build was successful. For example,

1. Execute project A.
2. Wait 3 days.
3. Execute project B (parameterized project).

A build should not be triggered in this scenario -

1. Execute project A.
2. Wait 2 days.
3. DO NOT execute project B. Don't do anything.

Note - Project B is parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a parameterized project, you need to:

1. Edit its Jenkinsfile to include the parameters; and
2. Execute the edited Jenkinsfile once so it would catch the schedule.

You can, in theory, save the schedule outside of Jenkinsfile, and build it from the scratch on executing the Jenkinsfile. In this case, you would need to:

1. Edit the schedule (that now resides outside of Jenkinsfile); but still
2. Execute the Jenkinsfile once so it would catch the schedule.

So, as you can see, there is a problem with your requirement.

In theory, you have the option of writing a new parameterized project (let's call it C) that will:

1. Wait 3 days.
2. Trigger project B to run at this time, with parameters of itself.

Your project A will then trigger (on the spot) the parameterized project C that will, in 3 days, trigger the parameterized project B.

Note that in case of Jenkins restart in these 3 days, your project B may run from the beginning, or not run at all.